# Limit access to pages only with internal links

Tags: wordpress, redirect, hyperlink

I'm developing a marketplace website based on Wordpress, and I have 2 sections of it that I want to make privately accessible only for the parties involved - one is profiles and the other one is projects. I think that the way to do it is to make these pages accessible only through internal links within the website - by doing it like this, I don't think there's a possibility for someone unrelated and external to land on a restricted page.

I've tried this code from another Stackoverflow question, but it doesn't work in my case:

```
/* at the top of page */
    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && realpath(__FILE__) == realpath( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ) ) {
        /* 
           Up to you which header to send, some prefer 404 even if 
           the files do exist for security
        */
        header( 'HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found', TRUE, 404 );

        /* choose the appropriate page to redirect users */
        die( header( 'location: /404.php' ) );
```

One of the pages I'm trying to limit access to looks like this: http://consult.law/author/ipetkov/

I'm still new to all this technical stuff, so any help from you on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but WordPress has functions for getting the current user, and checking if the user has the appropriate permissions.

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to make these permissions variable and not fixed - for example, you might not have permissions to view another user profile now and that's OK, but then, further on the other user could potentially send you a bid for a project posted by you on the website (sorry for getting a bit more specific here), and then you should be able to view his profile. But if he doesn't do so, then his profile should remain hidden for you. Hope it is a bit more clear now. I think restricting direct links to these pages should do the trick.